# How to connect web2py with mysql on Windows 10

Tags: python, mysql, windows, web2py

After adding

```
db = DAL('mysql://admin:admin@localhost/web2py')
```

I got this errors..

Failure to connect, tried 5 times: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Projects\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\base.py", line 457, in **init** self._adapter = adapter(**kwargs) File "C:\Projects\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters__init__.py", line 39, in **call** obj = super(AdapterMeta, cls).**call**(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Projects\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\base.py", line 369, in **init** super(SQLAdapter, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Projects\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\base.py", line 53, in **init** self.reconnect() File "C:\Projects\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\connection.py", line 154, in reconnect self.connection = self.connector() File "C:\Projects\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\mysql.py", line 51, in connector return self.driver.connect(**self.driver_args) File "MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 81, in Connect File "MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in **init** TypeError: 'password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

I have installed mysql, mysql-connector for python, mysql-client, python2.7 and so on

```
db = DAL('mysql://admin:admin@localhost/web2py')
```

I expecting this will be connect but not

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

uri = mysql://user:password@host/databasename

And also, use Python 3 goodluck :)))

Comment: web2py support only on python 2.*

Comment: No, web2py does support Python 3.